# PHP - Form Data to localhost Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp, localhost

Error:
The screen goes blank when submitting the form and there is no new record in the database. Any ideas?

My files:

Conn.php

```
    <?php


$connect =mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "gym");


if(mysqli_connect_errno($connect))
{
    echo "Error Connecting to Database!";
}


?>
```

Form.php

```
<html>

<head>

    <title>Gym Form</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


</head>

<body>

    <form action="Proccess.php" method="post">

    <span>Gym Membership Registration</span><br><br>

    <Span>Title: </Span><input type ="text" Value =" " name ="Title" /><br>

    <Span>First Name: </Span><input type ="text" Value =" " name ="Fname" /><br>

    <Span>Last Name: </Span><input type ="text" Value =" " name ="Lname" /><br><br>

    <Span>Gender: </Span><select name ="Gender">

        <option value ="Junior">Male</option>
        <option value ="Adult">Female</option>
        <option value ="Senior">Private</option>

    </select><br>

    <Span>DOB: </Span><input type ="date" name ="DOB" /><br><br>

    <Span>MembershipExpiry: </Span> <input type ="date" name ="MemX" /><br>

    <Span>MembershipType: </Span><select name = "MemType">

        <option value ="Junior">Junior</option>
        <option value ="Adult">Adult</option>
        <option value ="Senior">Senior</option>

    </select><br><br>

    <Span>Email Address: </Span><input type ="email" name ="Email" /><br><br>

    <input type="Submit" name="submit" value ="Submit Form">
```

An Proccess.php (where the error seems to be):

```
<?php

include 'Connect.php';?>

<?php

//variables

$title = $_POST['Title'];
$fname = $_POST['Fname'];
$lname = $_POST['Lname'];
$gender = $_POST['Gender'];
$dob = $_POST['DOB'];
$memx = $_POST['MemX'];
$memtype = $_POST['MemType'];
$email = $_POST['Email'];

//query

mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO records(Title,Fname,Lname,Gender,DOB,MemX,MemType,Email) 
values ('$title', '$fname', '$lname', '$gender', '$dob', '$memx', '$memtype', '$email')");
```

Error:
The screen goes blank when submitting the form and there is no new record in the database. Any ideas?

Database table is called records and has columns:

```
Title
First Name
Last Name 
Gender
etc
```

Please help me connect and upload the forms data to db.

Comment: `mysqli_query($connect"INSERT`  comma is missing also

Comment: mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT .............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add ',' after $connect like this:

```
mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO records(Title,Fname,Lname,Gender,DOB,MemX,MemType,Email) 
values ('$title', '$fname', '$lname', '$gender', '$dob', '$memx', '$memtype', '$email')");
```

Comment: Thank for trying to help me. The error has gone now, however, the screen goes blank when submitting the form and there is no new record in the database. Any ideas?

Comment: In your process.php, you are including connect.php, but your file name is conn.php. Fix that and replay.

Answer (score 0):

connection.php

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "gym") or die('Error Connecting to Database!');
?>
```

process.php

```
<?php

//variables

$title = $_POST['Title'];
$fname = $_POST['Fname'];
$lname = $_POST['Lname'];
$gender = $_POST['Gender'];
$dob = $_POST['DOB'];
$memx = $_POST['MemX'];
$memtype = $_POST['MemType'];
$email = $_POST['Email'];

//query

$sql = 'INSERT INTO records (Title, Fname, Lname, Gender, DOB, MemX, MemType, Email) VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?,?)';

if (! $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $sql)) {
trigger_error('Error: ' . mysqli_error($connection), E_USER_WARNING);
}

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssssssss', $title, $fname, $lname, $gender, $dob, $memx, $memtype, $email);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

mysqli_close($db);

redirect('Form.php');
```

Check this out http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php